# How to calculate confidence interval of dynamic model (force) output from parameters mean and standard deviation?

Tags: time-series, modeling, standard-deviation

I have a dynamic force model in time-series, let's say for example:

$F(t,x,\frac{dx}{dt}) = p1\cdot x + \frac{p1+p2}{p3} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} $

where p1, p2, p3 are parameters, x is displacement, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is velocity, and $F$ is force. 
I identify parameters of this model from experimental data using least squares optimization. 
I do it for four different observations that give parameter mean and standard deviation such as

p1 = 9.29 $\pm$ 0.4, 
p2 = 2.66 $\pm$ 0.2,
p3 = 82,32 $\pm$ 2.3

How do I then add standard deviations from the parameters to represent output $F$ with a standard deviation or confidence of interval of the model? In other words, how can I calculate the variance of the force based on the parameters with variance? Take into consideration that force depends on time.

P.S. The model I am using is a bit more complicated (in total 5 parameters)